# Change operator in a query?

Tags: views, 9

I'm working in a Drupal 9 website.

I need to change operator in my view query from != to <.
In a view i got two contextuals filters:

- The first to retrieve id from an entity reference field.
- The second to retrieve current node id.

In the second contextual filter, exclude is selected to be != in my query.

The result i need is to transform this != to < for show all nodes who got the same reference field ID AND an ID lower than current node id.
It's like a previous Articles by the same reference field!

My view query is :

```
SELECT "field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data"."created" AS "field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data_created", "node_field_data"."nid" AS "nid", "field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data"."nid" AS "field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data_nid"
FROM
{node_field_data} "node_field_data"
LEFT JOIN {node__field_entreprises_marque} "node__field_entreprises_marque" ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_entreprises_marque.field_entreprises_marque_target_id AND node__field_entreprises_marque.deleted = '0'
LEFT JOIN {node_field_data} "field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data" ON node__field_entreprises_marque.entity_id = field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data.nid
WHERE (("node_field_data"."status" = '1') AND ("node_field_data"."type" IN ('entreprise_marque'))) AND ((node_field_data.nid = '3259' )) AND ((field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data.nid != '22561' OR field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data.nid IS NULL))
ORDER BY "field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data_created" DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

What i need is :
field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data.nid < '22561'

I try like this:

```
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;


/**
* Implements hook_views_query_alter().
*/
function mymodule_custom_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {
  if ($view->current_display === '20_articles_precedents') {
    $view->query->where[4]["conditions"][0]["operator"] = '>';
  }
}
```

But nothing appens...

Answer (score 0):

I do it like that:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 * modifier la requete d'une vue
 */
function injector_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  if ($view->id() == '20_articles_precedents' && $view->current_display == 'block_1') {
    $field_name = 'field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data.nid != :nid2 OR field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data.nid IS NULL';
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        if ($condition['field'] === $field_name) {
          $condition['field'] = 'field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data.nid < :nid2 OR field_entreprises_marque_node_field_data.nid IS NULL';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but i think you need to implement the `hook_views_api()`:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_api().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_views_api() { 
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME'),
  );
}
```

Besides that on your hook I think it's not necessary pass the operator selector, like this:

```
if ($view->current_display === '20_articles_precedents') {
  $view->query->where[4]["conditions"] = '>';
}
```

But I dont't run any test of this.

Comment: I don't think so.